# SOAP UI project request object

Tags: web-services, wcf, soapui

I am working with SOAP UI project to test web service.
When i build a request automatically using SOAP UI right click and generate rquest.
Request is generated with default '?' value with all the properties requires for request.
My request object contains bunch of properties nearly i can say 100-150. I have to set this manually.

My question is that is there any way to generate request object with default values?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a Request Template.

1. Under the Interface, find your method.
2. Right click on the method, select New Request, give it a name, click OK.
3. Define your default values. Close the Request editor.
4. Right-click on the Request you named in step 2, select Add To test Case. Follow through with the rest of the prompts.